# If $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal to each other with respect to the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, they are also linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a Euclidean $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with a general scalar product $\langle \cdot, 
 \cdot \rangle$. Let $v,w$ with $v\neq 0$ and $w\neq 0$. Show: If $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal to each other with respect to the scalar product $\langle \cdot, 
 \cdot \rangle$, they are also linearly independent. (It should be a general scalar product)

Not really sure how to start. I would assume, that they are linear dependent, but that didn't lead to any good solution.

Let $v=\lambda w, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\langle v,w\rangle=0\dots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$av+bw=0$ implies that $<av,w>+<bw,w>=b<w,w>=0$ and $b=0$ since $w\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

From $w= \lambda v$ and $<v, w>= 0$ you immediately have 
$<v, w>= <v, \lambda v>= \lambda <v, v>= 0$ 
Since neither $\lambda$ nor $<v, v>$ is 0, that is a contradiction.